# DJANGO - python manage.py inspectdb - ERROR - TypeError: translation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'codeset'

Tags: python, django, django-models, mysql-python

I have a database with tables and relationships between those tables in MySQL Workbench and I am trying to connect/integrate with Django.

I have specified it settings.py in my Django project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'data_storage',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

When I run `python manage.py inspectdb` or `python manage.py inspectdb > DjangoWebPage/models.py` in (VS Code) terminal, it shows an ERROR: `TypeError: translation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'codeset'`

Full prompt:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp> python manage.py inspectdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute    
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 94, in <module>
    class Group(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1583, in contribute_to_class
    self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1051, in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    'verbose_name': _('%(from)s-%(to)s relationship') % {'from': from_, 'to': to},
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 149, in __mod__
    return str(self) % rhs
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 113, in __text_cast        
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 75, in gettext   
    return _trans.gettext(message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 286, in gettext
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 199, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 90, in __init__
    self._init_translation_catalog()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 131, in _init_translation_catalog
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 119, in _new_gnu_trans
    return gettext_module.translation(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: translation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'codeset'
```

Produce Django models in models.py from tables present in MySQL.

I was following this:
https://rafed.github.io/devra/posts/database/how-to-connect-django-to-existing-database/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: translation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'codeset'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74406706/typeerror-translation-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-codeset)